# How to move add to cart button after the image in product listing(catalog_catagory_view) page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.5

How to move add to cart button after image in product listing (catalog_catagory_view) page in magento2 using xml file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create or open the **catalog_category_view.xml** layout file in your theme. This file should be located in **app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/**.

Add the following XML code to the layout file

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.media" after="product.media"/>
```

Save the file and clear your Magento 2 cache.

If the above XML code doesn't work, you may need to modify it according to your specific theme's layout structure.

Comment: I have already tried but this code doesn't work

Comment: <move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.media"/>
Try this...

Comment: this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Create or open the **catalog_category_view.xml** layout file in your theme. This file should be located in **app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/**.

Add the below code to XML layout file

```
 <move element="category.product.addto" destination="category.product.image" after="category.product.thumbnail"/>
```

Save the file and clear your Magento 2 cache.